Is it possible to create a system within Zoho Mail that can copy emails matching specific keyword criteria to a WorkDrive folder?
I want to create a system where emails containing certain keywords in the subject line are automatically copied to a specific WorkDrive folder. Could anyone help and outline the steps to achieve this? Initially, I considered creating a script and applying filters, but I couldn't find any APIs for creating, updating, or deleting filters. Additionally, obtaining new scopes for every request is somewhat cumbersome. If this approach isn't optimal, could someone suggest an alternative method?
I tried to use api endpoint of filter CRUD provided by ChatGpt but taht all was wrong and i hav'nt found them in docoumenation

Keep in mind that SO is not a code-writing service. Furhermore asking recommendations on tutorials, libraries, etc. are off-topic on SO. Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

@DarkBee Kindly just tell me does Zoho provide us Filter CRUD? I have not found anything anywhere
